# reactjs TypeError: Object(...) is not a function when using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to export a normal functional component using the react hooks but I am getting this error.

> TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

when I remove the hooks and export it without any states it works. Exporting the same code as a Class component also works.

```
import React,{ useState } from 'react';

const  Mycomponent = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Mycomponent;
```

here is how I am importing and using functional component.

```
import Mycomponent from './mycomponet';
class MYClassComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Mycomponent />
    }
}
```

I am using `react 16.6.3` and used `create-react-app`.

Comment: What bundler and bundler settings are you using? What does the compiled/transpiled code look like? Have you verified that `useState` is in fact a function? What version (and distribution file) of React are you using?

Comment: I am using react `16.6` and used `creat-react-app`

Comment: @saurabh - React hooks are available from v16.8 onwards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I am using react 16.6.3...

That's the problem. Hooks were added in v16.8, so `useState` in your code is `undefined`.

(This is one of those times that transpiling hid the error from you [not that you have much choice if you need to support older environments]. If that had been a native `import` statement, it would have failed with a useful error saying that React didn't have a `useState` named export. But when using a CJS or AMD version of React, your code gets converted to something doing `var useState = React.useState;` and so it doesn't error out, it just gives you `undefined` — which isn't a function. :-) )